# Cakephp 3.6.14: make selection in controller for selection box in view and disable it

Tags: php, forms, cakephp, combobox, field

I have a `Users` table with 2 fields (among others): `id | name`. In the controller I am passing an `$userid`, if this `$userid` is not null then the form field for the user must be filled with the name of the user, if `$userid` is null then this field must be a selection box with all the users of the application.

I have built successfully the part of the selection box (where `$userid` is null) but I can't figure out (if `$userid` is not null) how to select the correct name in the selection box and make it disabled so it cannot be changed.

Here is the **Controller Code**:

```
public function add($userid = null)
{ 
       ......
       $usersTo = $this->Tasks->UsersTo->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
       ......
}
```

And the **View code**:

```
 .....
 echo $this->Form->control('assigned_to', ['options' => $usersTo, 'empty' => true]);
 .....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

> Controller Code:

```
public function add($userid = null)
{ 
 /* Set userid on your view if user id is not empty code */
 if (!empty($userid)) {      
  $this->set(compact('userid'));
 }
   ......
   $usersTo = $this->Tasks->UsersTo->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
   ......
}
```

> View code:

```
$disabled = false;
$selectedUser = '';
if (!empty($userid)) {
  $disabled = true;  // set disabled property true if userid is not empty
  $selectedUser  = $userid;  // set userid as selected user
}

echo $this->Form->control('assigned_to',['options' => $usersTo, 'empty' => true, 'value' => $selectedUser, 'disabled' => $disabled]); // pass disabled and selectedUser here
```

Comment: There is a bug though... if selection is disabled and the name of the user is selected when I submit the form `$this->request->getData('assigned_to')` is null :(

Comment: if I remove `'disabled' => $disabled` then it works, it passes the correct value

Comment: yes because you  used disabled. You have to use readonly instead of disabled. Cakephp doesn't send the value of element if it is disabled.